# Android 2D game: should I use a frame layout or a game engine?

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

Let's say in my app, I have a 2D side view of a car.

On this car you can have three different changeable parts: the body, back tire, and front tire.

Should I just use a team layout to stack on each image according to what the user selects? Should I go for a game engine that takes care of the entire view and what the car looks like?

In just trying to dabble in 2D game design and was wondering the best way to accomplish this. If there is a better method than either of those two, please feel free to suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a game engine. If you feel you are proficient in Java, I would suggest using something called Libgdx. More information can be found here:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Libgdx is good for 2d games and you can develop 3d as well. If you specially want to develop 3d games however, I would suggest using a platform called Unity.

Comment: I've heard of Unity before, just haven't messed with it. Can I use Unity for 2d games as well? I think it would be best to learn Unity through 2d, so if I ever do 3d, I've got a leg up.

Comment: Yes, Unity can be used for 2d game development.

Comment: There are many online courses you can take to learn Unity because it is very widely used and popular.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into Unity.